# Is $L^i(K_4)$ regular for all $i \in \mathbb{Z}^+$? If so, find the general formula for the degree of $L^i(K_4)$?

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

Let $K_4$ represent the simple, fully connected graph of 4 vertices. Let $L$ represent the operator so that $L(K_4)$ is the line graph of $K_4$. Let $L^1(K_4)=L(K_4), L^2(K_4)=L(L(K_4)),$ etc. Is $L^i(K_4)$ regular for $i \in \mathbb{Z}^+$? If so, find a general formula for the degree of $L^i(K_4)$.

The work I have done thus far is equated the general formula for the number of edges to be reliant on the degree of a given graph. To formalize, let $n$ be the number of vertices and let $k$ be the degree of the graph; the number of edges in $L^i(K_4)$ equates to $n {k \choose 2}$. But this doesn't bring me any closer to answering the first part of the question meaning it cannot yet be used in the proof. And using it to find the degree $k$ of a given graph $L^i(K_4)$ would be algebraic work that I cannot justify combinatorically.

I would appreciate any assistance.

Answer (score 1):

Hints.

1. If a graph $G$ is regular, then $L(G)$ is also regular.
2. Let $d_i=\operatorname{deg}(L^i(K_4))$.
   Then we have $d_{i+1}=2(d_i-1)$ for all $i\geq1$ and $d_1=4$.

Here is a picture, which I hope explains the last formula.

[image]

Comment: The 2nd hint is not obvious (albeit I will definitely consider the why, the how, etc etc), but the first hint gave me great direction to begin the proof.
Thank you so much for your assistance! I greatly appreciate your time!

Comment: Start with the cases where $i=1,2$ and see what degree you get.

Comment: Hmm… The formula definitely follows, I won’t argue there, but to double $d_i-1$ of the previous line graph… I guess I’m having trouble finding a combinatorical explanation why I am able to make that claim. I do have a theorem that makes use of that result using the characteristic polynomial of the adjacency matrix so maybe I can attempt viewing from a linear algebra perspective.

Comment: @HeyaLily  I supplemented my answer.

Comment: That diagram helps amazingly, thank you! I am presuming the blue dots to be an indication of "and so on".

Comment: @HeyaLily Yes exactly.